# app.module error with finding a name

Tags: angular, typescript

I am currently creating an angular 2 project, however I cannot get passed these two errors I am getting in my console

ERROR in [default] /Users/~/src/app/app.module.ts:35:4 
Cannot find name 'SelectItem'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/~/src/app/app.module.ts:36:4 
Cannot find name 'Message'.

I have added the two imports into my app.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import {SelectItem, Message, Header} from 'primeng/primeng';

@NgModule({
 declarations: [
  AppComponent,
 ],
 imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  FormsModule,
  HttpModule,
  SelectItem,
  Message,
  Header
 ],
 providers: [],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: What is the absolute path for primeng/primeng?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup

According to this, you want to import the specific modules in your `app.module.ts`, not the components by themselves.

Try this:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import {SelectButtonModule} from 'primeng/primeng';

@NgModule({
 declarations: [
  AppComponent,
 ],
 imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  FormsModule,
  HttpModule,
  SelectButtonModule,
 ],
 providers: [],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Next, you should be able to use the SelectButton in your components/templates.

Comment: So what if i want to use those interfaces, as i looked into the library and i couldn't find the module i need to import

Comment: I think you are looking for SelectButton right? Then you should use `SelectButtonModule` as explained here: http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/selectbutton

I have changed my answer to SelectButtonModule.

Answer (score 1):

I think the classes you are importing are not modules. So they should not be in the imports segment of you `@NgModule`. If I inspect the library you are using PrimeNG, they appear to be interfaces which don't need to be imported at all.

What you need to do is import all the modules you want to use from the library. This will enable you to use the components from those modules in your application.

Comment: So what if i want to use those interfaces, as i looked into the library and i couldn't find the module i need to import

Comment: What specific component of PrimeNG do you want to use?